# Modal height and width adjustment

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Trying to adjust the height and width of the modal, however without any luck.

I have tried:

```
 max-height: 80vh; //
```

&

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
.modal-dialog {
width: 1024px;
margin: 30px auto;
```

&

```
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
```

All do very "strange" things to the modal. I.e move it to the left of the screen and don't actually make it bigger. Here's my CSS for the modal:

```
modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EBEAEA;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5384616;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;  
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tms9vz0k/1/

Thank you!

Comment: can you fork that up in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't seem to be working in jsfiddle even after adding cdns. Do check your code

Comment: Thanks, probably because i've only added the modal part, the rest is alot to mess around with.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: what is the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/tms9vz0k/3/

Comment: Thanks George! I want the modal box to almost fit the size of the screen

Comment: Did you check my fiddle?https://jsfiddle.net/tms9vz0k/7/

Comment: I did but it doesn't give the modal box, any bigger than I currently have it :)

Comment: do you want to reduce the height & width?

Comment: No increase, to give a much larger modal.

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tms9vz0k/7/

Comment: Thanks, this is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/kl9m2i

Answer (score 0):

Try this css.

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .modal-dialog {
        width: 1024px !important;
        margin: 30px auto;
        max-width: 1024px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again - appreciate all your help BUT https://prnt.sc/kla348 Doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: I had an extra bracket in there, sorry. It' hasn't adjusted the modal size.... not sure what's going on.

Comment: Where you added this css?

Comment: Clear the cache and check

Comment: I added this to the bootstrap.css file :)

Comment: You need to add this css in your active theme style.css